# working with threads on pageload

Tags: asp.net, multithreading

When my asp.net page loads, it needs to get data from 2 webservices. I want to make the data retrieval processes work concurently. How can I do this and update Label1 with the text result from WS1 and label2 with the result from WS2? I don't know how the code should look like in order to be able to update the controls on the page.

Comment: how much time takes your webservices to provide data? It seems that you are new to webservice concept

Comment: if your webservice is not taking too much time to provide data then you can easily set label1 and label 2 values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This post](http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2005/06/17/async-pages-in-asp-net-2-0.aspx) should be helpful